# Does SQLite create a numeric index that I can sort/fetch on?

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift, core-data

I'm working on my first CoreData application and I'd like to sort my data based on how it was inserted into database.

**My question is do I need to create an 'id' attribute for my entity or is there is a computed index that I can sort on?**

[image]

Comment: Yes you need to create your own id and increment it based on the last saved record. I'd go for a different approach and add a `createdAt` attribute that you can sort by. If you go with `id` you will always need to keep track of the last id used or fetch the highest id before you can insert a new record.

Comment: @Rog, thank you for your recommendation, I will certainly keep that in mind. In this situation I am dealing with a static amount of items which I insert into sqlLight using a seed method. These items are for a settings menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic index created. You should add an attribute of type `NSDate` and you can sort by that.

One convenient place to implement this is in the `NSManagedObject` subclass.

```
public override func awakeFromInsert() {
    createdAt = NSDate()
}
```

And to sort:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt" ascending: true)]
```

Comment: considering that my app calls my entity LogItem I think i should've mentioned that I'll be housing a static list of items whose values will change per user (application settings basically). Do you still recommend an NSDate or will an NSNumber suffice?

Comment: Yes, stick with `NSDate`. It just stores a number in SQLite anyway, so there is no performance difference. But the resulting code is much more readable and explicit about your intentions.

Comment: good to know, I'll follow your advice. thanks for the answer!